# pyspark gives following error Failed to create local dir in /tmp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i am new to spark and trying pyspark and spark-shell
in both cases i am getting this error 
pyspark gives following error

> > ERROR storage.DiskBlockManager: Failed to create local dir in /tmp. Ignoring this directory. java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temp directory (under /tmp) after 10 attempts!

can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the folder ? and if there is enough space in /tmp folder ?

Comment: actually permssions are good and space also looks good, like 42% free so i am confused. is there any way we can change /redirect the working folder path

Comment: Try with *spark.local.dir* conf  : `export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.local.dir=/newFolder..."`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark - java IOException :Failed to create local dir in /tmp/blockmgr\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238121/spark-java-ioexception-failed-to-create-local-dir-in-tmp-blockmgr)

Answer (score 0):

If there is enough space left on your folder, try

```
chmod ugo+rwx /tmp
```

My tmp folder is somehow deleted and after created a new one I fixed it by this